# Force the compiler to use a function

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I am playing a bit with some functions to make aproximations to some common functions (sqrt, sin, cos and the like) and I was wondering if I could 'study' the performance and precision of the C library I am using and the hardware instruction (if available)

So, my question is: Is there a way to tell the compiler that for some functions I want the 'library version' and for others the 'hardware version' ? (and if possible, giving the compiler freedom to optimize the library version, but without using the hardware instruction).

Something like:

```
library_fun(x);  // <-- compiled to the library version
hardware_fun(x); // <-- compiled to the hardware version (if available)
```

**EDITED:**

Okay, my question wasn't very self-explicative, new trial:

I am assuming that my C library has some kind of 'software-fallback' implementation for some mathematical functions in case the hardware doesn't have them. I was wondering if I could call that (that's what I was calling `library_fun`) to check it's precision/performance/just curiosity if I could.

Also, I would be able to use the hardware instruction (if it exists and is available).

As a more detailed 'example', in my code I have the function `sqrt`. If I check the assembly output I get a `sqrtsd` instruction. So, no call to sqrt whatsoever.

Comment: What do you mean by HW? HW interface is the assembly language... Can you provide a real example. I just can't understand what exactly you are trying to test.

Comment: Well, the "library" version of `sin`, for example, is most likely very complex and involves approximating the value using polynomials if there's no hardware support, but then it may decide to use CPU's hardwired algorithms instead, like `fsincos`. I don't think there's an easy way to ensure that the library functions are indeed "pure software" other than modifying `glibc` code on your own, which should be possible if you're running GCC on Linux.

Comment: @szczurcio That's mostly what I was looking for: A way to ensure that the 'sofware' version of the function was being called, instead of just to a hardware instruction. If you think that that would be too complex, maybe I am better by just 'extracting' the code from `glibc` by myself.

Comment: If you examine the library source code, you may be able check which internal functions it calls for different processor variants. If you're very lucky, they might be externally linkable.

Comment: This question makes more sense for builtin functions. Your compiler may insert builtin code rather than call a library. Sometimes you don't want to use the builtin code.

Answer (score 1):

By listing the libraries in a particular order, the linker will search these in order, using the first occurence of a symbol (function). Libraries are searched after your compiled source code was searched, so any symbol in your code is preferred over a version in the library.

Note that there can be conflicts or incompatibilities, for example if a library function uses other functions from that library which were already found in an earlier listed library or object.

This behavior may further depend on the tool chain you are using, but the behavior I described is what I generally see is happening.

EDIT: as per your edit of your question: a compiler might check the hardware the compiler is running on to decide to use library functions or CPU instructions for certain math work. Then possibly the compile has switches to direct it to use/not use those instructions, for example if you are compiling for a different platform. VC2008 has:

- `/arch:[SSE|SSE2]` to specify  the architecture for code generation using the Streaming SIMD Extensions (SSE) and Streaming SIMD Extensions 2 (SSE2) instructions.
- `/fp:precise` disables intrinsic [floating point]; the standard run-time library routines are used instead.

Comment: My main problem is getting the library version (I mean from glibc) that doesn't compile to a `sqrtsd` or `fsqrt`. For the hardware version I know that I can always use some inline assembly.

Comment: Please clarify your question. It is not clear what you want. Note that a "library version" doesn't "compile". It is already compiled and can only be linked.

Comment: I have edited the question, if it is still unclear, please, ask anything else you want. And thanks.